# Help With (supposedly) Simple Command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a map that has a pile of blocks (15 total)  and need to know when one has been broken because the game will end when all have been broken.(I am using Exotic Blocks so there is no chance of there being another of it.)
THIS IS A UPDATE
 I am wondering if it would be possible to use a scoreboard to test how many blocks a player has broken of a type if someone could show me how to do this I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: I dont know if the testfor command would do what I need

Comment: Like I said; Arqade works better when it looks like you've tried to solve your own issue.  If you have an idea, give it a shot!  At least you're trying, and that helps immensely.

Comment: If you could respond ASAP because my friends and family are very anxious for the release of the new game xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command for each block, connected to a repeating circuit:

```
/testforblock x y z [blockname] [Damage] {dataTags}
```

Where the "[blockname]" the block's name, and "x y z" are the coordinates of the block. With mods, the name can vary from something like `minecraft:grass` to a modded ID like `mocreatures:fish_egg`, so it's good to look up the ID beforehand with mods involved. You can hook these command blocks up to your scoreboard system with a redstone torch on a block to change the signal around. If you don't know how to build one, or something's wrong with yours, just leave a comment, and I will add the scoreboard commands.

Another way is to use the command:

```
/testforblock x y z minecraft:air
```

It will test for when a block isn't there. You don't have to use a redstone torch with that, and it's way simpler, so I definitely recommend it.

Comment: That's a terrible way to test for a large amt. of blocks, you would need a single cmd block for each one. If all he cares about is when it's empty, he should have an empty space somewhere, and use `/testforblocks`.

Comment: Sorry... a small error... just fixed it. (wrote this post just after i woke up.)